# Why is the force that moves an airplane forward called THRUST and not PULL?

Tags: aircraft-physics

As we know, there are four forces acting upon an airplane. Thrust ($T$), Drag ($D$), Lift ($L$), and weight ($W$).

Since most propeller-driven airplanes over history have had the propeller mounted in the front, the power or forces generated were to pull, not to push. So why is it called ***thrust*** (the meaning of which is equivalent to push), and not ***pull***??

Comment: How do you pull air?

Comment: Well, wouldn't that would be about like calling lift "suck"?  And we all know that lift doesn't suck.  Also, you'd have a problem explaining jet propulsion, and even more so rockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thrust is the force reaction from accelerating a gas from here to over there.  If the element creating the thrust, a propeller, is in front of the engine, it's called a "tractor" configuration because it's pulling the engine, like a tractor (any normal front engine airplane).  If the prop is at the back, or more correctly, behind the engine, it's a pusher configuration (A Lake Buccaneer amphibian is a pusher even though the engine is amidships, not at the tail, because the prop is on the back of the engine itself).  Lots of other designs have put the prop all the way at the back.

In a jet engine, you don't really have an element pushing or pulling the engine itself because the thrust reaction is actually happening inside the engine, mostly in the area ahead the convergent nozzle of the tailpipe where the flow is forced to accelerate. So for jet engines it's just thrust.

Comment: After I checked again, the first design of airplane, that was the Wright flyer, was a canard rather then tail. The propeller is behind the wing to push the airplane. So, very possible it is the reason the name is called thrust, which literally means pushing. While the resistance suffered by the airplane is called drag.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing and pulling should be considered in relation to the air, not the engine. For many means of propulsion, there simply is little in the way of any pulling going on. Best example of this is a rocket, all force comes from the push out the back. With jet engines, the inlet often creates drag, it does not suction the aircraft forward normally. Propellers are a bit more tricky in this regard when you examine the math, as the lack of mass addition or significant heating makes the "inlet" and "outlet" conditions conserve a lot better, but it is still the aircraft acting on the air, not the other way around, and the air that has been acted on normally ends up behind, not in front of the aircraft.

Comment: Or, is it has relation to the previously using propeller, ship?

Comment: @AirCraftLover I don't understand the sentence you just wrote, but I'm guessing you meant to write: "Or, is it related to an older vehicle that has a propeller—a ship?"

Comment: If you think about it, suction is not pulling air, it is the pressure of the atmosphere pushing air into a place where you've created a partial vacuum.